# Search Within Text Files (.doc, .docx, .pdf etc) in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, docx

I want to make a module which search within a files (file type: .doc, .docx, .pdf). By using "file_get_contents()" I can find the files but for that I have to specify the location where all the files are. In my case I have the files in many folders (like this: C:\xampp\htdocs\cats1\attachments\site_1\0xxx..) the files are always store in the "0xxx" folder (By other application). I just want to specify the path so that no matter how many "folders" the "0xxx" folder contain, it search within it. I am quite new to php, please do help. My code for this application is below.

```
 <?php
 $matched_files =   array();
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $skills    =   $_POST['skills'];
 $experience=   $_POST['experience'];
 $location  =   $_POST['location'];
 $path = 'C:\Docs';
 $dir = dir($path);
 // Get next file/dir name in directory
 while (false !== ($file = $dir->read()))
{   
if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
{
    // Is this entry a file or directory?
    if (is_file($path . '/' . $file))
    {
        // Its a file, yay! Lets get the file's contents
        $data = file_get_contents($path . '/' . $file);

        // Is the str in the data (case-insensitive search)
        if (stripos($data, $skills) !== false and (stripos($data, $experience)  !==   false and (stripos($data, $location) !== false))) 
        {
    $matched_files[]    =   $file;

            }

    }
            }
            }
          $dir->close();
          $matched_files_unique =   array_unique($matched_files);
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: they are not text files, you would have to extract the text to search them

Comment: Does your database actually store the text of the files, or does it store the names and locations of the files?

Answer (score 4):

The files that you're mentioning are not text files.  Additionally, it is not a good idea to store these files' contents in a database.  Here's the approach I would take:

1. Store these files using their hash (generated from something like
   `sha1()`) as the file name to store the files to the filesystem.
2. Create a table to store the metadata (file name, data uploaded, hash
   name) of the files.
3. Within the above-mentioned table, create a `text` column to store
   the extracted text from the files.  Each file type will require a
   different tool.  For instance, for PDFs, you can use something like
   `pdftotext`.
4. Do your searches in the database by selecting the filename (hash)
   from the table where the keywords are contained within the text
   column (or whatever search criteria you want).
5. Open the file named by the returned hash and return that file to the
   user.